# Как настроить подсказки в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Попробовал поработать на VS Code. Всё нравится, но максимально бесит работа подсказок. Можно ли настроить их?
Из основных проблем:

- лишние методы(типа ввожу "console." и в списке предлагаемых вылазит "length")
- отображение кучи лишних переменных(в подсказках показываются переменные из других функций, свойства других объектов).

Можно ли сделать подсказки в VS Code более адекватными?

Comment: А какой язык используется?

Comment: @KonstantinGaliakhmetov, не думаю что язык что-то меняет, но JS

Comment: По поводу console. , попробуйте не писать console, а сразу писать log тогда в интелисенс будет то что вам надо))